# Why does a Python collections.Counter get mutated when its values are referenced

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I'm not quite sure what's happening here:

```py
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

c1 = defaultdict(Counter)
c2 = defaultdict(Counter)

c1[1][2] = 3
c1[2][3] = 4

keys = c1.keys()

for i in keys:
  c2[i] = c1[i]
  
  for k in keys:
    if k < i:
      c2[i] += c1[k]
      
c1
```

That displays:

```py
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {1: Counter({2: 3}), 2: Counter({3: 4, 2: 3})})
```

Why does `c1` get mutated? I know one can eliminate the mutation by changing `c2[i] = c1[i]` to `c2[i] += c1[i]`. But my goal is to understand why the snippet above mutates `c1`.

Comment: You have two dicts of counters, then you create additional link to existing counter from the first dict in the second, so  `c2[i] is c1[i] == True`, it's the same counter instance. You could use `c2[i] = c1[i].copy()` if you want, it's more explicit than `c2[i] += c1[i]`.

Comment: Woof you nailed it. Can you please make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yes, sure I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have two dicts of counters, then you create additional link to existing counter from the first dict in the second, so `c2[i] is c1[i] == True`, it's the same counter instance. You could use

```
c2[i] = c1[i].copy()
```

if you want, it's more explicit than `c2[i] += c1[i]`.